# Postgis Distance calculation on huge datasets

Tags: postgis, distance, nearest-neighbor

We have `7,512,694` records in our table,

Columns:

`id, name, lat (numeric), lon (numeric), location (geometry(Point,4326))`

Indexes we created: 
`create index on table using gist(location);`

and of course rest of the columns are also indexed.

**Requirement:**
We need to get places that are in 100m distance of a given point. The queries I am using right now are taking more than 100s (yes seconds:()

These are the queries I have tried so far:

**Query 1:**

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT name FROM businesses
WHERE ST_Distance(location::geography, 'SRID=4326;POINT(-121.696176 38.15399)'::geography) < 100 ;
```

Result:

```
Seq Scan on businesses  (cost=0.00..2997214.91 rows=2504231 width=543) (actual time=5982.917..120110.083 rows=6 loops=1)
    Filter: (_st_distance((location)::geography, '0101000020E6100000A510C8258E6C5EC09DF4BEF1B5134340'::geography, '0'::double precision, true) < '100'::double precision)
    Rows Removed by Filter: 7512688
Planning time: 0.138 ms
Execution time: 120110.129 ms
(5 rows)
```

**Query 2:**

```
explain analyze SELECT name FROM businesses
WHERE ST_DWithin( ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-121.696176 38.15399)',4326),26986), ST_Transform(location,26986), 100);
```

Result:

```
Sort  (cost=3104972.93..3105223.35 rows=100169 width=543) (actual time=120216.612..120216.619 rows=6 loops=1)
Sort Key: name
Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
->  Seq Scan on businesses  (cost=0.00..3072341.85 rows=100169 width=543) (actual time=39426.948..120216.532 rows=6 loops=1)
    Filter: ((st_transform(location, 26986) && '01030000206A6900000100000005000000E758D42C93364EC16028183E1ADA3941E758D42C93364EC16028183EE2DA3941E758D42C2F364EC16028183EE2DA3941E758D42C2F364EC16028183E1ADA3941E758D42C93364EC16028183E1ADA3941'::geometry) AND ('01010000206A690000E758D42C61364EC16028183E7EDA3941'::geometry && st_expand(st_transform(location, 26986), '100'::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin('01010000206A690000E758D42C61364EC16028183E7EDA3941'::geometry, st_transform(location, 26986), '100'::double precision))
    Rows Removed by Filter: 7512688
```

What method can I use to decrease the query time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not getting any benefit from your spatial index, because you're storing your locations as `geometry(Point, 4326)` but querying them either as `geography` (Query 1) or as `geometry(Point, 26986)` (Query 2).

Any of the following changes would fix this:

**Query 1:**

Switch your `geometry` column to type `geography`

```
ALTER TABLE businesses ALTER COLUMN location
  SET DATA TYPE geography USING geography(location);
```

Or, add a `geography` column, populate it based on `location`, and maybe set up a trigger to maintain this in the future

```
ALTER TABLE businesses ADD COLUMN geog geography;
UPDATE businesses SET geog = location::geography;
```

Or, create a functional index on `location` casted to `geography` (slower than the above two options):

```
CREATE INDEX ON businesses USING gist(geography(location));
```

**Query 2:**

Store your geometry in the projection you're using for queries:

```
ALTER TABLE businesses ALTER COLUMN location 
  SET DATA TYPE geometry(Point, 26986) USING ST_Transform(location, 26986);
```

Or, create a functional index on your transformed geometry (slower than the above option):

```
CREATE INDEX ON businesses USING gist(ST_Transform(location, 26986));
```

Which of these solutions is the best depends on your particular situation. In general, distance calculations using `geometry` will be faster than calculations using `geography`, and indexes on a stored column will be faster than functional indexes.

Comment: Thanks so much for the elaborate answer, I am updating the column with geometry 26986 as you suggested for Query 2. It will take some time because of the large dataset. I'll get back to you as soon as it is done.

Comment: its done, should I create an index again on the location column now?

Comment: Update: without creating the index again, I am getting the result in 10s now :D

Comment: Infact 2 secs with `st_dwithin` and 10s with `st_distance`

Comment: How many results in the return? For a small result set, a "within distance" query should return in under 100ms. Maybe drop and re-create the index. Also, since you re-wrote the whole table, consider running `VACUUM FULL` on it.